# HTML5 Boilerplate with DOJO and not jQuery

Tags: html, dojo, html5boilerplate, boilerplate

HTML5 Boilerplate seems like a great way to start a new project.  I noticed that it includes jQuery library by default.  I do not see jQuery as required, and am planning to use DOJO, but would like to make use of the HTML5 Boilerplate files.  Is jQuery required in anyways to use the HTML5 Boilerplate template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jQuery isn't require. After all, the HTML5 boilerplate is simply said, a boilerplate/template and can be altered.

If you don't need jQuery you can simply remove it by removing [these two lines](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L24-L25):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

None of the other scripts (modernizr, main.js, plugins.js or the Google analytics script) requires jQuery to run, so that's not a problem.